# CLion warning without any way to disable it

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++20, clion

I'm getting the following (probably) inspection warning in CLion: `warning: bitwise operation between different enumeration types is deprecated`

There is no context menu option to disable it and I can't find it anywhere in the settings. I can see the warning popup window (see screenshot) when I hover over it with the mouse, but there isn't any information there except the warning text (no error code, intention name or anything at all that gives me a clue as to where this warning comes from)... very strange.

[image]

I thought it comes from C++20 compiler warning [C5054](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/c5054?view=msvc-170) from the MSVC compiler so I tried to disable it in CMake with `target_compile_options(engine PRIVATE -wd5054)` but it didn't work.

Note: it bothers me since it appears all over my code and I fix the original code that causes it since it comes from in an external library.

Any idea how do I disable this annoyance?

Comment: Please don't post error messages as pictures, thanks.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2712#issuecomment-685212390

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I did post the error message text... (I posted also the picture to show that there aren't any buttons to disable the warning).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. About that link - I would have tried it but there is no information at all in the warning (I don't know the error code or even exactly where it's coming from)...

Comment: You said it's C5054

Comment: I said I think it is, but anyway that's the compiler warning id - I'm not sure it's the same as the Intellisense inspection error code. Anyway I tried it with both `#pragma diag_suppress 5054` and `#pragma diag_suppress C5054` - neither worked :(

Comment: Hmm they say they are showing intellisense error codes now, maybe your version is not up to date? Sorry here my competence ends.